# Authetification erro in MongoDB Atlas database when trying to connect

Tags: mongodb-atlas

I tried to setup and use Mongo Atlas using the setup steps of the section **Setting Up the Mongo db database** ,in the Mozila Express tutorial that you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment), then I got authentication error when running the populatedb.js file mentioned in that tutorial:

```
This script populates some test books, authors, genres and bookinstances to your database. Specified database as argument - e.g.: populatedb mongodb+srv://cooluser:coolpassword@cluster0.a9azn.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true
MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 11, high_: 1620398123 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 11, high_: 1620398123 }
}
(node:12916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:12916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12916) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
FINAL ERR: MongooseError: Operation `authors.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
node populatedb mongodb+srv://notmyfault
okok:%40mongoDB1@cluster1.zbmx1.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true
This script populates some test books, authors, genres and bookinstances to your database. Specified database as argument - e.g.: populatedb mongodb+srv://cooluser:coolpassword@cluster0.a9azn.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true
MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620398181 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620398181 }
}
(node:12935) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/pc/Documents/node_express_tutorial/local_library_app_tutorial/express-locallibrary-tutorial/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:12935) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12935) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
FINAL ERR: MongooseError: Operation `authors.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
[1]+  Done                    node populatedb mongodb+srv://notmyfaultokok:%40mongoDB1@cluster1.zbmx1.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true
```

What I did was click on connect button in the created Cluster of the mongoDB Atlas, copy the url for connect to application. Change the passworld field and the database name field to the mongoDB-Atlas password and the name of the created database in the cluster.

So the authentificaiton error I don;t get as I think i put the correct password in the database url and also I check for if the url encoding is correct as well.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the error now, it is actually that you can create a user and password for a created database. And so I was using the username and password for the Atlas website and not that of the database itself. New that I created a new database and username and password for that database, I could use that database for my app and it worked fine!

But the steps that i used to arrive at the solution is not straigh forward. I actually started looking at how to implement a search engine for the mongoDB database and found a tutorial that ask me to connect via the mongoDB compass. I used the mongoDB compass to connect with the atlas username and password and it didn't work. but then I was like, this can't be possible. Then i removed the password completely and it seems to connect!.

Afterwards, I also tried again the Express tutorial and remove the password but it still give cannot have empty string password error. But then I was like I'm just gonna create a new account. and try it out. When I created the new account and the new database, they actually asked me to create a username and password for the new database! And this is where I found out that you also have a usernam and password for the created database.

I don't know what happen before, maybe it was cause I created the database long time ago and forget that a database uses a username and password as well.

SO it is solved and I'm moving on the 4th part of the tutorial.